# Посоветуйте API для перевода речи в текст

Tags: android, android-sdk

Требуется создать приложение, позволяющее конвертировать речь в текст и записывать его в виде массива\или одного слова. Сказанные слова в динамик переводить в строку\строки проще говоря.

Подскажите куда копать? гугл посылает на готовые приложения для пользователей. Как называется API для изучения?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech/, это один из вариантов, так же api для распознавания речи есть у яндекса и т.д.

Comment: Не могли бы оформить это как ответ, и ключевое слово указать для поиска?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cloud.google.com/speech, это один из вариантов, так же api для распознавания речи есть у яндекса и т.д Попробуй поискать - api для распознавания речи